# form:select incorrectly rendering as multiple="multiple"

Tags: spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a select box that is showing up as a multi-select box when I want it to be a drop down.  I cannot figure out how to change it.

```
<form:select path="roles" id="role" cssClass="form-control">
    <form:options items="${roles}" itemLabel="description" itemValue="id"/></form:select>
```

The html that is produced as a result of this (see below) has the multiple box attribute added.

```
<select id="role" name="roles" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="1">Administrator</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="_roles" value="1"/>
```

It also produces that hidden input and I don't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You misnamed this all as JSTL. None of this all is JSTL. This is just a Spring MVC taglib. A custom or 3rd party JSP taglib is absolutely not per definition JSTL or so. To learn what JSTL really is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: please post your controller code and you added JSTL taglib library.